# Submit Button is not getting selected..no error also

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML code:

```
<button id="welcomeContinue" class="btn btn-primary padlock active-removal" type="submit">
<span class="icon-padlock"></span>
 CONTINUE
</button>
<input class="btn btn-primary padlock disabled" type="hidden" value="" title="Continue" name="continueanonymousSubmit" alt="Continue">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:continueanonymousSubmit">
```

code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("welcomeContinue")).click();
```

How can i select submit button and proceed to next page

Comment: Are they(botton, input) in a form?

Comment: Are you sure, you are locating correct element?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using `submit()` method on a button instead of clicking.
2. Also, may be some info should be added for submitting to work: some required fields should be filled. Check this option
3. There are may be some JS scripts running that prevent submit for working

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click()
```